# How to make a checkbox to enable checkboxes in a fragment

Tags: android-studio

I need help making a Checkbox that when is checked it enables the other 4 checkboxes so i can decide which dice rolls
this is the part of the code where the botton make the app works is a dice app
the 4 checkboxes are disabled at the start of the app

```
private void rollDice () {
        int d1 = this.random.nextInt(3) - 1;
        int d2 = this.random.nextInt(3) - 1;
        int d3 = this.random.nextInt(3) - 1;
        int d4 = this.random.nextInt(3) - 1;
        if (cb1.isChecked()) {
            switch (d1) {
                case -1:
                    iv_dice1.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice_1);
                    break;
                case 0:
                    iv_dice1.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice_2);
                    break;
                case +1:
                    iv_dice1.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice_3);
                    break;
            }
        }
        if (cb2.isChecked()) {
            switch (d2) {
                case -1:
                    iv_dice2.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice_4);
                    break;
                case 0:
                    iv_dice2.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice_5);
                    break;
                case +1:
                    iv_dice2.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice_6);
                    break;
            }
        }
        if (cb3.isChecked()) {
            switch (d3) {
                case -1:
                    iv_dice3.setImageResource(R.drawable.d_1);
                    break;
                case 0:
                    iv_dice3.setImageResource(R.drawable.d_2);
                    break;
                case +1:
                    iv_dice3.setImageResource(R.drawable.d_3);
                    break;
            }
        }
        if (cb4.isChecked()) {
            switch (d4) {
                case -1:
                    iv_dice4.setImageResource(R.drawable.d_4);
                    break;
                case 0:
                    iv_dice4.setImageResource(R.drawable.d_5);
                    break;
                case +1:
                    iv_dice4.setImageResource(R.drawable.d_6);
                    break;
            }
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: what's your problem? you mentioned your request but didn't clarify what problem did you encounter.

Comment: well i dont know how to make the checkbox enable the other checkboxes sorry is my first time working on android studio

Comment: that's easy just make on checked event on main check box then enable other checkbox and put them disable by default and also you need to keep checkbox status because on scroll view the status of check box would be unchecked

Comment: sub check boxes need to have a unique static status to keep them checked when checked and unchecked when unchecked .

Comment: umm how i make a checked event?

Comment: just put a dot( . ) on checkbox object in syntax then all functions will be visible .

Answer (score 0):

You should try to first find your checkbox object:

```java
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxID);
```

Then you attach an EventListener listening for Change-Events and there you can enable your other checkboxes:

```java
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        if ( isChecked )
        {
            // enable other checkboxes
            cb1.setEnabled(true);
            cb2.setEnabled(true);
            cb3.setEnabled(true);
            cb4.setEnabled(true);
        }

    }
});
```